# В какой ситуации слова в кавычках пишутся со строчной буквы?

Tags: кавычки

Есть такое предложение: *От бесполезных попыток ответить на вопрос «Кто виноват?» начала пухнуть голова*. Будет ли первое слово в кавычках с маленькой буквы и можно ли как-то определять подобные случаи в дальнейшем?

Просто лично мне всегда казалось (чисто на уровне восприятия), что если перед подобными выражениями не стоит двоеточия – то есть они не выражают прямую речь, – то в таких случаях всегда будет использована строчная буква. Но вот я увидел данное предложение и сразу засомневался...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bGgPCNW.png

Answer (score 0):

Слова пишутся в кавычках в зависимости от того, что они обозначают.

Если слово является наименованием завода, фабрики, журнала, газеты, романа, кинофильма, спортивной команды и пр., то его берут в кавычки и первое слово в нем пишется с большой буквы, например:

фабрика "Коммунарка";

завод "Металлист";

журнал "Мамино солнышко";

газета "Комсомольская правда";

роман Л. Толстого "Война и мир";

хоккейная команда "Динамо";

кинофильм "Трактористы".

Иногда и имя существительное нарицательное, прилагательное, глагол тоже берут в кавычки, если это слово употребляют в необычном для него значении, чаще в противоположном, например:

Ну, и "красота" тут у вас! ( то есть неубрано).

Что за "малыш" к нам пришел? (а пришел молодой человек, ростом под потолок с бицепсами).

Вот все говорят "понаехали" на нас.

Answer (score 0):

Словарь крылатых слов и выражений.

> Кто виноват? Название романа (1841 — 1845) Александра Ивановича
> Герцена (1812— 1870). Роман «Кто виноват?» был впервые опубликован в
> журнале «Отечественные записки» 1845—1846 гг. Упоминается обычно как
> второй «извечный русский вопрос», после вопроса что делать?, как
> правило, иронически — мол, этим вопросом можно задаваться сколь угодно
> долго, если нет конкретных дел.

Обратите внимание на второй "извечный" вопрос, упомянутый в словарной статье. Получается, что при наличии явного указания на "извечность" вопроса и кто виноват? и что делать? можно писать с маленькой буквы и без кавычек.
В первом приближении, крылатое выражение "кто виноват?", расположенное в середине или конце предложения, я бы использовал в зависимости от контекста:

1. "Кто виноват?" - при отсутствии упоминаний о "извечных" вопросах;
2. "кто виноват?" - при наличии упоминаний о "извечных" вопросах, и желании подчеркнуть ироничность;
3. кто виноват? - при наличии упоминаний о "извечных" вопросах и нейтральной позиции.

А форма: кто виноват - вообще не крылатое выражение.

Таким образом, если в примере словосочетание "кто виноват" используется автором  в качестве крылатого слова, то правильно ..."Кто .. с прописной буквы.
А если там вопрос типа - кто это сделал, то написание и обособление словосочетания "кто виноват" - неверное.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:

*От бесполезных попыток ответить на вопрос **«кто виноват?»** начала пухнуть голова.*

**Пояснение**

1. Проблема здесь в том, **как применить** правило Розенталя к конкретному предложению: выбор прописной или строчной буквы, постановка двоеточия.
2. Выбираем **строчную букву:** хотя это отсылка к известному произведению Герцена, но фраза уже воспринимается как нарицательная.
3. **Двоеточие** не ставим: это же не вывеска, да и не предложение.

**[Розенталь §122. Прямая речь внутри авторских слов](https://evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm)**

**Примечание.** Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это ***«не хочу»*** поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Предположение дневального, что «**взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе**», все больше собирало сторонников (Фадеев); Он вспомнил пословицу «**Не плюй в колодец..**.» и отошел в сторону; С криком «**Спасайте детей!**» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова **предложение, надпись, выражение** и т.п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие, например: Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные, также отдаются напрокат и починяются старые» (Пушкин).